# share a folder using ironpython

Tags: python, visual-studio, ironpython

I've written a (iron) python script which shares a folder on a remote server.

```
import getopt
import ctypes as C
from ctypes.wintypes import (LPCWSTR)

class SHARE_INFO_2(C.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('shi2_netname', LPCWSTR),                
                ('shi2_type', C.c_int),
                ('shi2_remark', LPCWSTR),
                ('shi2_permissions', C.c_int),
                ('shi2_max_uses', C.c_int),
                ('shi2_current_uses', C.c_int),
                ('shi2_path', LPCWSTR),
                ('shi2_passwd', LPCWSTR)]    

def Share(server, shareName, dir):
    i = C.c_int()
    info = SHARE_INFO_2()

    STYPE_DISKTREE = 0

    info.shi2_netname = shareName
    info.shi2_path = dir
    info.shi2_type = STYPE_DISKTREE
    info.shi2_remark = "Shared from script"
    info.shi2_max_uses = -1
    info.shi2_passwd = ""

    return C.windll.Netapi32.NetShareAdd(server, 2, info, C.byref(i)) == 0

server = "rs01"
dir = "c:\\temp"

Share(server, "Temp", dir)
```

It's created in Visual Studio 2015. When this script is run from within Visual Studio it runs fine. The folder is shared. But running the script from the commandline:

> ipy C:\PythonConsole\SysTasks.py

Gives the exception: System.AccessViolationException from somewhere within the iron python code.
I get the feeling that this has something to do with the structure declaration/memory layout of the structure but not sure.

Anyone knows what's wrong here?

Comment: Do you have tried to start it as administrator?

Comment: Yes it has the same problem. Maybe it's the last parameter in NetShareAdd? NetShareAdd(server, 2, info, C.byref(i))

Comment: Hmm, `byref` seems not to be the problem. It seems that the info parameter cause the problem.

Comment: yeah, NetShareCheck has a byref argument too but no structures to pass in and that call always succeeds. Really no clue why it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution!

The SHARE_INFO_2 struct had to be converted to a byte array with buffer function and that array had to be passed to NetShareAdd.

```
def Share(server, shareName, dir):    
    info = SHARE_INFO_2()

    STYPE_DISKTREE = 0

    info.shi2_netname = shareName
    info.shi2_path = dir
    info.shi2_type = STYPE_DISKTREE
    info.shi2_remark = "Shared from script"
    info.shi2_max_uses = -1
    info.shi2_passwd = ""
    info.shi2_current_uses = 0
    info.shi2_permissions = 0xFFFFFFFF

    i = c_int()

    bytearray = buffer(info)[:] # SERIALIZE INTO BYTES

    return windll.Netapi32.NetShareAdd(server, 2, bytearray, C.byref(i)) == 0
```

Comment: Good you found a solution :)